# Intersect of all polygons from the same layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection

I have various polygons within one layer in QGIS.

As a result I need the area where all polygons overlap as shown in the picture.
Is there a way to do?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the processing Toolbox, under **SAGA**, you have a treatement called **polygon self-intersection** which seems to be what you're seeking ...

*(as a result, i seem to recall you will have **a new field** aggregating the id of all the polygons intersecting)*

Answer (score 2):

If you need only the geometry and not the attributes, just running normal *Vector→ Geoprocessing Tools → Union* with no *Overlay layer [optional]* should do the trick.